# Packing 1 WebService and 2 MDB's in a WAR file (JEE5)

Tags: java, jms, ejb, war, java-ee-5

I would like to pack in a war file a webservice and 2 mds's but no matter what i do i do not see the MDS's being deployed.
The other alternative i have is to pack my app in a ear and there to put the war file and jar files for mdb's but I want to know if it is possible to pack this into a WAR file.
Is there any special thing  I need to specify in web.xml file or in ejb-jar.xml to see the MDS's deployed ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All EJBs need to go in an EAR file.  The WAR spec only applies to web apps with servlets and JSPs.

So your solution is to create the WAR file separately and put that into your EAR along with your MDBs.

Comment: Look at this please:http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipio.html and http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/beta/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.express.doc%2Finfo%2Fexp%2Fae%2Fcejb_ejbinwar.html .The first article is from jee6 ...so not ok for jee5 ?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, just put everything into an EAR file.

I have never used an MDS file, but if you search in here (http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12529_01/webcenter.1013/b31073/cb_deploy.htm) they have this, which sounds like it may apply to you:

> Development MDS Repository Path :
>   ../../mds/;../../  Enter new MDS
>   Repository Path :
>   C:\java\srdemo_oc4j\mds\SRDemo